# At what points does vector equation represent $\bar{x}=\lambda \bar{a}+\alpha \bar{b}$ with ...

Tags: geometry

At what points does vector equation represent $\bar{x}=\lambda \bar{a}+\alpha \bar{b}$ with $\alpha+\lambda=1$ if $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are the position vectors of $A$ and $B$

i don't have a clear idea of how solve this exercise. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec x=\lambda\vec a+(1-\lambda)\vec b=\lambda(\vec a-\vec b)+\vec b$$So the given equation represents the line joining the points $A(\lambda=1),B(\lambda=0)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the set of vectors parallel to AB. You can prove this by noting that $\alpha = 1 - \lambda$ and then using basic vector addition and subtraction.